# What is the relationship between a map and its first return map when it comes to equidistribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

Let $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu, T)$ be a measure preserving system. In this setting, $X$ is a (compact if need be) topological space, $\mathcal{X}$ is a Borel sigma algebra, and $T$ continuous. Let $A \in \mathcal{X}$ be a measurable set with positive measure $\mu(A) > 0$. Let $T_A : A \to A$ be the first return map.

Now, we say that $T$ equidistributes if for all compactly supported continuous functions $f \in C_c(X)$ and for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have that $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f(T^nx) \to \int_X f\, d\mu.$$

Is there a relationship between $T$ and $T_A$ when it comes to equidistribution?

Comment: Is $\mu$ a probability measure? Is the convergence for every or just $\mu$-a.e. x? What does the $C_c$ refer to in $C_c(X)$ if we are only in a measure space?

Comment: You're right, $\mu$ is a probability measure. I edited the OP and added conditions on $X$.

Comment: It looks as if your definition of 'equidistributes' mean that $T$ is ergodic? In which case $T_A$ (with restricted measure) is also ergodic. The other way around need not be true.